# Grails + Jquery, pure HTML not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails

I'm trying to use ajax and grails. This page should be independent, so I can't use gsp tags, only pure HTML.

```
<head>
    <title>Teste</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Test</legend>
            <label>User:
                <input type="text" name="username" />
            </label>
            <label>Code:
                <input type="text" name="code" />
            </label>
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
<script>

    $("form").submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "http://localhost:9091/teste/paciente/index",
          dataType: "text",
          data: $(this).serialize(),
          success: function(data) {alert("oi")},
          error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
          }  

        })
        return false;
    })
</script>
</body>
```

Grails

```
 class PacienteController {

        def index = {
            def username = params.username
            def code = params.code

            //response.contentType = "application/"
            render text: 'sent successfully', contentType: 'text/plain'

        }
    }
```

I can debug my controller, but after that, I get an error from jQuery (empty message). I don't know what Grails does behind scenes, but can't return data at all. What I missed?

Comment: you mean thrownError is empty? how about ajaxOptions? what is its value?

Comment: does the ajax call make it to your controller? Can you println something in PacienteController to make sure of that?

Comment: This works fine for me in Grails 2.1 as long as I have the page  as an html file directly in the `web-app` directory (`web-app/index.html`).  Doesn't work as a gsp. I can get to to alert with 'oi' or 'sent successfully' if I change the success alert to `alert(data)`

Comment: thank you for your answers. @aldrin, I receive 0, 'error' and empty for xhr.status, ajaxOptions and throwError, respectively, so no clue what's going on.

Comment: @Hoàng Long, yes, I can reach my Controller through a break point.I can even get username and code values. The problem is really the way back.

Comment: @Kelly good to know, actually my grails version is 1.3.7. The client(ajax caller) is located on a different project, so I'll put on web app and give it a try. Maybe I can work while searching for a solution.

Comment: Ok, I put my html on web app. It's working now, but I really want to know. Is this a grails issue? A container issue? Ajax behavior? I never tried to access another server content through Ajax. The projects that I worked for always have ajax requesting content on the same project/server, so I can't tell. Just to clearify, my ajax caller was running in http://localhost:8080/ and my grails project in http://localhost:9091/.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to create a answer for this.  It's a cross domain Ajax request that is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a cross-domain AJAX issue. Standard AJAX is restricted to returning data to he same domain as the request is made to. You can use JSONP to get around this, but you have to return the data as JSON.

So you could change your controller to do this:

```
def result = ['status': 'sent successfully']
render "${params.callback}(${result as JSON})"
```

The `params.callback` in there is a callback function created and sent by automatically by the request.

As far as the request goes, I think all you have to modify is `dataType: 'jsonp'` but I'm not an expert on that part by any means.  See the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) if you need more...

Comment: Glad to help!  If this does answer your question can you accept the answer so it doesn't show in the unanswered status?

Comment: Good question by the way - I'm going to give you an upvote once my votes get reset.